# how to search a word or text with in command prompt

Tags: command-line, grep

For example i have printed a mysql big table from database on cmd which has 500 fields in it .How do i search for a particular word with in command prompt. I know `grep` is used to search strings or words in files ,but how do i do that in cmd.

Comment: you can pipe the output of a command to `grep`. eg: `cat mybigfile.txt | grep "find_this_word"`

Comment: Why not using `REGEXP` in `mysql` directly ?

Comment: Want to make fun of me?

Answer (score 3):

If you're using the `mysql` SQL prompt, you can [tell it to use a different "pager"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10177465/grep-in-mysql-cli-interpretter) (that is what it uses to output results).

```
mysql> pager grep searchstring
PAGER set to 'grep searchstring'
```

Now everything you run will get passed through `grep searchstring`.

Answer (score 1):

Using `grep`

```
grep 'particular_word' your_mysql_dump
```

---

Or you could use `mysql` and a `SELECT` statement or, as @Oli said in his [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/662510/367165) `PAGER grep particular_word`. Reset the `PAGER` with

```
nopager
```

EG:

```
mysql> nopager
PAGER set to stdout
```

*Examples*

```
mysql> use mysql
Database changed

mysql> show tables;
+---------------------------+
| Tables_in_mysql           |
+---------------------------+
| columns_priv              |
| db                        |
| event                     |
| func                      |
| general_log               |
| help_category             |
| help_keyword              |
| help_relation             |
| help_topic                |
| host                      |
| ndb_binlog_index          |
| plugin                    |
| proc                      |
| procs_priv                |
| proxies_priv              |
| servers                   |
| slow_log                  |
| tables_priv               |
| time_zone                 |
| time_zone_leap_second     |
| time_zone_name            |
| time_zone_transition      |
| time_zone_transition_type |
| user                      |
+---------------------------+
24 rows in set (0,01 sec)

mysql> PAGER grep user
PAGER set to 'grep user'

mysql> show tables;
| user                      |
24 rows in set (0,00 sec)

mysql>
```

Or

```
mysql> use mysql
Database changed

mysql> select host,user from user where host="localhost" and (user="root" or user="");
+-----------+------+
| host      | user |
+-----------+------+
| localhost |      |
| localhost | root |
+-----------+------+
2 rows in set (0,00 sec)

mysql> PAGER grep root
PAGER set to 'grep root'

mysql> select host,user from user where host="localhost" and (user="root" or user="");
| localhost | root |
2 rows in set (0,01 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: I am puzzled to see you are copy pasting the solution given by Oli. Probably best to just link instead of taking it over.

Comment: @fedorqui If you look at the subsequent edits and [the chat-room transcript](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/23471832#23471832), it looks like cross-fertilisation...

Comment: @Fabby Thanks for the info. However, I find it weird that this is discussed there and the fact you assume it is fine, even though I don't see Oli saying it anywhere. To me, this seems like bad netiquette from the user posting the answer. And if he wants to improve the answer provided by Oli, the best thing is to update *that* answer.

Comment: @fedorqui if you got a problem with this downvote and if you want to keep this going either head over to chat and ask Oli directly or make it a question on meta. Comments are not for these kind of discussions.

Comment: @Rinzwind I downvoted and left an explanation, which is what I do when I downvoted. Then I replied to Fabby's message (you could also tell him/her about this, I guess). I don't think this is my issue at all, I just pointed an aspect in the place it should be mentioned - the answer itself so that others can see the behaviour. By the way, I also went to the chat and explained my point there. TL;DR: to me, the problem is with the answer using another one, not with the person pointing it out.